# Kivy size change changes positioning

Tags: python, kivy

I think I still don't get the positioning for Kivy. I have this bar (hungerBar) that has size (100, 10) and I want to place it at the middle of the window. The bar will change its size by (-5, 0) every second. However, with the way that I am setting up right now, its position was also changing as the size changes. Here's parts of the code.

```
class HungerBar(Widget):
    def hunger_dec(self):
        if (self.size[0] > 0):
            self.size[0] = self.size[0] - 5
    def hunger_inc(self, increase):
        if (self.size[0] + increase < 100):
            self.size[0] = increase + self.size[0]

class ShootingGame(Widget):
    hungerBar = HungerBar()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ShootingGame, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        randX = random.choice([0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.9])
        self.enemy = self.drawEnemy(randX)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.enemy.drawWalking, 1)

        self.hungerBar = self.drawBar()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.hungerBar.hunger_dec, 1)


    def drawBar(self):
        bar = HungerBar()
        self.add_widget(self.hungerBar)
        return bar

class GameScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GameScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.game = ShootingGame()
        self.add_widget(self.game)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)

sm = ScreenManager()
game_screen = GameScreen(name='game')
sm.add_widget(game_screen)

class ShootingApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    ShootingApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
<HungerBar>:
    Color: 
        rgb: (0, 1, 1)
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: root.width/2, 30
            size: 100, 10
```

Thank you!

Comment: There are a lot of bugs, please correct them.

Comment: Do you consider the positioning starts from bottom, left? ie. if you change size of your object, the only point that keep constant in the bottomxleft

Comment: @kiok46 could you kindly point out some of the bugs? I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: @bigOTHER bottom left is the default one, right? If so, yes. But, I don't know why the bar would move constantly to the left until it disappears from the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined the position in relation of the `HungerBar` size:

```
canvas:
    Rectangle:
        pos: root.width/2, 30
```

`X` is the half of the width. `root` here refers the top element which is `HungerBar`.